# Material UI React modal blurred components on some area

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I get some blur effects when using Chrome Mobile Device tool, when the modal appear to at least the height of the screen, i get this effect;

[image: weird effect]

But when i zoom in, it disappear, zoom out and it comes again.

[image: weird effect disappear]

It works fine on desktop, even if the height is greater the the viewport.